# Maven project: module not found even with correct dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-platform-module-system

I'm trying to build a Java module with Maven but I keep getting the same error (module not found) with every dependency when I run `mvn compile`. Neither Intellij IDEA nor VSCode give me any error before compiling.

I think it's a JPMS proble since if I delete `module-info.java` it works flawlessly.

java version:openjdk 20.0.2 2023-07-18

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.4 (Community Edition)

Apache Maven 3.8.7

I built a smaller example which represents the problem, note that I get the same error with other dependencies like jakarta.xml.bind or Docx4J.

```
myapp
|---pom.xml
|---src/main/java
      |---module-info.java
      |---com/andreagenovese/myapp
           |---Main.java
```

Main.java

```java
package com.andreagenovese.myapp;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LogManager.getLogger();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.andreagenovese</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

module-info.java

```java
module com.andreagenovese.myapp {
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    exports com.andreagenovese.myapp;
}
```

The error

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/geno/Documents/Programmi/Java/myapp/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/geno/Documents/Programmi/Java/myapp/src/main/java/module-info.java:[2,32] module not found: org.apache.logging.log4j
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.816 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-04T00:32:03+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myapp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/geno/Documents/Programmi/Java/myapp/src/main/java/module-info.java:[2,32] module not found: org.apache.logging.log4j
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Check the documentation https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/runtime-dependencies.html which shows the module definition etc... also upgrade to most recent version instead of using older versions (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/release-notes/index.html) also I would recommend to use the bom file (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html)

Comment: I still get the same error, I suspect it's a problem with JPMS because it works if I delete `module-info.java`

Comment: If you delete `module-info.java` that means you are working with classpath and not with modules anymore... and it looks like you haven't read the docs because the module name of the `log4j-core` is `org.apache.logging.log4j.core` which is not what you have defined here... what you have defined is the module name of the `log4j-api`... you have to defined both of them...

Answer (score 0):

Log4j will not work with only core library. You can try with these dependency :

```
        <properties>
             <log4j.version>2.13.0</log4j.version>
        <properties>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You're right but even with the correct dependencies, it doesn't work. As I said it's not a problem with this specific library, but with every single one I've tried so far. I suspect it has to do with JPMS because if I delete `module-info.java` it works flawlessly.